# Two identical emails can only be connected to one

Tags: c#, connection, pop3, data-extraction

I ran into a problem. I want to connect to my email box and pull data from it, everything works as it should. The problem is, but when I switch to another email (both are outlook, one is for example m@test.cz - this works, s@mailbox.cz - this one not), I get this error when connecting

> ERR Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

I have been given new access to the email that is displaying this error. The login credentials are good, both mailboxes are POP3 enabled.
Do you know what could be causing this or is it just a triviality?

Read this answer, I'm not sure that sollution is just change password.
[Unable to Connect/Read Outlook 365 Mail Business Account with Pop3Client c#, even correct credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916078/unable-to-connect-read-outlook-365-mail-business-account-with-pop3client-c-eve)

```
using EAGetMail;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;

namespace PopServer
{
    
    class EmailParser
    {
        private string serverName;
        private int port;
        private bool isSSLuse;
        private string username;
        private string password;
        public static string GetBodyText = " ";

        public EmailParser(  bool isSSLuse, string username, string password)
        {
            this.ServerName = "outlook.office365.com";
            this.Port = 995;
            this.IsSSLuse = isSSLuse;
            this.Username = username;
            this.Password = password;
            PopServer(this);
        }

        public string ServerName { get => serverName; set => serverName = value; }
        public int Port { get => port; set => port = value; }
        public bool IsSSLuse { get => isSSLuse; set => isSSLuse = value; }
        public string Username { get => username; set => username = value; }
        public string Password { get => password; set => password = value; }
        
        static string _generateFileName(int sequence)
        {
            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            return string.Format("{0}-{1:000}-{2:000}.eml",
                currentDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss", new CultureInfo("en-US")),
                currentDateTime.Millisecond,
                sequence);
        }
        

        public void PopServer(EmailParser emailParser)
        {
           
            try
            {
                bool help = true;
                //Timer for reseting main method
                Timer timerRestartApp = new Timer();
                timerRestartApp.Interval = 500;
                do
                {
                    string localInbox = string.Format("{0}\\inbox", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

                    if (!Directory.Exists(localInbox))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(localInbox);
                    }

                    MailServer oServer = new MailServer(emailParser.ServerName,
                            emailParser.Username,
                            emailParser.Password,
                            ServerProtocol.Pop3);

                    oServer.SSLConnection = emailParser.IsSSLuse;
                    oServer.Port = emailParser.Port;

                    MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");
                    oClient.Connect(oServer);


                    MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
                    Console.WriteLine("Total {0} email(s)\r\n", infos.Length);



                    for (int i = 0; i < infos.Length; i++)
                    {
                        MailInfo info = infos[i];
                        Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                            info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);


                        Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                        Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                        Console.WriteLine("Date:" + oMail.ReceivedDate);
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);
                        Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}\r\n", oMail.TextBody);
                        GetBodyText = oMail.TextBody;




                        string fileName = _generateFileName(i + 1);
                        string fullPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", localInbox, fileName);


                        oMail.SaveAs(fullPath, true);
                    //Delete email-isRead
                    //oClient.Delete(info);
                }


                    oClient.Quit();
                    Console.WriteLine("Completed!");

                    if (timerRestartApp.Interval == 0)
                    {
                        help = false;
                    }



                } while (help != false);

            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Port 995 is POP3S. Not all outlook server are configured to use same port number (protocol).  If you are inside a firewall you may only be allowed to connect to the mail server inside the firewall and not outside.

Comment: @jdweng Hi and thank you for your comment. How could I know if I am allowed to connect to the mail server outside?

Comment: Most Corporate Networks only allow you to use companies Outlook.  Port Forwarding is used at firewall to send all email port numbers to the Corporate Email Proxy Server.  The proxy server than validates the credentials.  If the email account is not on the proxy the connection fails.  If code works on your home PC than it is not the software.

Comment: So the problem is probably with mailbox. Not with my code?

Comment: You need to check the SMTP webpage for you email server to make sure you are using the correct settings.  Not all mail server use the same SMTP options.

Comment: Outlook use SMTP. Sorry If I have stupid questions. Working with emails for first time.

Comment: Maybe the problem could be with emails as themself. Maybe they are different? How could I know this?

Comment: SMTP is Simple Mail Transport Protocol.  There are different options and port number which has to be compatible with the mail server you are using.  An Outlook Email Server is configurable and different companies (gmail, yahoo, mailbox.cz,test.cz ) can use different settings.

Comment: @jdweng I go an idea. The problem maybe with OAUATH2?

Comment: Not AUTHOR2.  You may need to enable SSL (really TLS) but as I said the options would be specified on the email SMTP webpage.